# Bash script to extract values of each variable

Tags: bash, unix

I have a variable with multiple values seperated by ':' , how can I get those fetched seperately to receive values of abc, cde story, bjd in a bash script?

```
abc: 10
cde story: 123abc
bjd: I have some values
```

Comment: The above _values seperated by ':'_ are `abc`, `10\ncde story`, `123abc\nbjd` and `i have some values`. This contradicts _values of abc, cde story, bjd_.

Comment: You can have spaces in the variable names i,e, "cde story"

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your question. Are these variables stored in a separate file, like 'vars.txt'? It would be very helpful for you to provide some more context.

That said, check out https://linuxhint.com/bash_split_examples/ for some examples of how to split a string in bash. The TL;DR is this:

If you have a bash variable:

```
text="Hello:World"
```

and you want to split it by a delimiter, ":", you must use the IFS variable.

```
IFS=":"
```

This seems to be a special bash variable that affects how the `read` command works.

So for you, it might look something like this:

```
some_var="10:123abc:i have some values"
IFS=":"
read -a var_array <<< "$some_var"
abc=${var_array[0]}
cde_story=${var_array[1]}
bjd=${var_array[2]}
echo "$abc, $cde_story, $bjd"
```

The output of which is:

```
10, 123abc, i have some values
```

Comment: I have stored some command output in this variable. so it has multiple line in it